Uncommitted changes in github workflow only
Does anyone ever get this during the CI deploy? I'm not sure if this is related to VSCode or what. I've tried several different methods to check if I have any uncommitted changes, and I simply do not, from what I am aware of. Can anyone point me in the right direction?
##[debug]/usr/bin/bash -e /home/runner/work/_temp/889d18d7-4e16-4585-bc22-73d9033c4d9b.sh
17:35:24 [ .. ] installing terraform linux-x86_64
Archive:  /home/runner/work/crossplane-provider-vultr/crossplane-provider-vultr/.cache/tools/linux_x86_64/tmp-terraform/terraform.zip
  inflating: /home/runner/work/crossplane-provider-vultr/crossplane-provider-vultr/.cache/tools/linux_x86_64/tmp-terraform/terraform  
17:35:25 [ OK ] installing terraform linux-x86_64
17:35:25 [ .. ] generating provider schema for vultr/vultr 2.21.0
17:35:27 [ OK ] generating provider schema for vultr/vultr 2.21.0
Cloning into '/home/runner/work/crossplane-provider-vultr/crossplane-provider-vultr/.work/vultr/vultr'...
17:35:28 [ .. ] go generate linux_amd64

Generated 12 resources!
17:36:04 [ OK ] go generate linux_amd64
17:36:04 [ .. ] go mod tidy
17:36:04 [ OK ] go mod tidy
17:36:05 [ .. ] checking that branch is clean
 M config/schema.json
17:36:05 [FAIL] There are uncommitted changes after running make generate. Please ensure you commit all generated files in this branch after running make generate.
make: *** [build/makelib/common.mk:446: check-diff] Error 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
##[debug]Finishing: Check Diff

on my local machine
make check-diff 
13:42:59 [ .. ] generating provider schema for vultr/vultr 2.21.0
13:43:00 [ OK ] generating provider schema for vultr/vultr 2.21.0
13:43:00 [ .. ] go generate linux_amd64

Generated 12 resources!
13:43:09 [ OK ] go generate linux_amd64
13:43:09 [ .. ] go mod tidy
13:43:09 [ OK ] go mod tidy
13:43:09 [ .. ] checking that branch is clean
13:43:09 [ OK ] branch is clean

$git status --porcelain | grep .
$
$git diff -b config/schema.json
$
git status
On branch terraform-v2.21
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/terraform-v2.21'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

